# Gamma density plot: dgamma working while own function returning error

Tags: r, plot, gamma-function

I am trying to plot a Gamma density function for the parameters (shape) alfa=3457 and (rate) beta=84. If I do this using:

```
curve(dgamma(x,shape=3457,rate=84),from=35,to=50,xlab="posterior theta",ylab="density")
```

everything works out just fine and I get the density centred on ~41. While if I first construct the density as:

```
para_density = function(x,s=3457,r=84,N) ((r^s)/(gamma(s)))*x^(s-1)*exp(-r*x)
```

and then plot it with:

```
curve(para_density(x,s=3457,r=84,N=N),from=0,to=100)
```

R tells me gamma(s) returns Inf, which is sensible given its meaning.

How come then I can plot it with identical parametrisation using the plot and dgamma functions?

Thank y'all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just use logarithm then

Code (untested!)

```
mygamma <- function(x, s, r) {
    l <- s*log(r) - lgamma(s) + (s-1.0)*log(x) - x*r
    exp(l)
}
```

UPDATE

Yes, it works

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x))
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(x) dgamma(x,shape=3457,rate=84))
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(x) mygamma(x,s=3457,r=84))
p <- p + xlim(35.0, 50.0)
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Severin, I thought about using logs, but my next question would then be if R uses the log-Gamma as an option when alfa is too large since I can plot it with its density function (I could not find the underlying code used by R for the Gamma density)? It doesn't seem to be the case looking at the R help function...

Comment: @GiacomoCapelli Frankly, I have no idea how it is done internally. Another option would be something like Stirling asymptotics and carefully combine terms to avoid overflow